# Why busy waiting has not been removed in this code?

Tags: operating-system

I am new to OS course and i was studying about Synchronization Technique in OS. I came across to semaphores and found two operations wait() and signal() as :

```
wait(S)
{
     while( S <= 0)
     {
           ;
     }

     S--;
} 

signal(S)
{
     S++;
}
```

Ok , i can understand the problem of busy waiting with following implementation , so new definition has been given as :

```
typedef struct
{
     int value;
     struct process *list;

}semaphore;

wait(semaphore *S)
{
    S->value--;

    if(S->value <= 0)
    {
         add this process in S->list;
         block();
    }
}

signal(semaphore *S)
{
    S->value++;

    if(S->value <= 0)
    {
        remove a process P from S->list;
        wakeup(P);
    }
}
```

Now , i read that "We have not removed busy waiting , instead we have shifted it from entry level code to critical section."

**Now can anybody tell me why there is a busy waiting with new definition , i think we are putting process in waiting list , so there should not be busy waiting ?**

Comment: We can't make any claims about how `block` is implemented, including if `block` is using a busy wait or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032304/why-busy-waiting-moved-from-the-entry-section-to-the-critical-sections-of-applic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why busy waiting moved from the entry section to the critical sections of application programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032304/why-busy-waiting-moved-from-the-entry-section-to-the-critical-sections-of-applic)

Answer (score 0):

There is no busy waiting in you code.

However, to use the above `wait()` and `signal()` methods, you must make a further development for them as the operations `S-->value++;` in the `wait()` method and `s->values--;` in the `signal()` method access the shared variable `S` and thus it become a critical section problem. This raises the busy-wait in the solution for this critical section problem.