# Why busy waiting moved from the entry section to the critical sections of application programs?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore, critical-section

I'm reading "operating system concepts 10th".

It gives a non-busy-waiting definition of semaphore:

```
typedef struct {
  int value;
  struct process *list;
} semaphore;



wait(semaphore *S) {
  S->value--;
  if (S->value < 0) {
    add this process to S->list;
    sleep();
  }
}

signal(semaphore *S) {
  S->value++;
  if (S->value <= 0) {
    remove a process P from S->list;
    wakeup(P);
  }
}
```

It says:

> It is important to admit that we have not completely eliminated busy
>   waiting with this definition of the wait() and signal() operations. Rather,we have moved busy waiting from the entry section to the critical
>   sections of application programs. Furthermore, we have limited busy
>   waiting to the critical sections of the wait() and signal() operations

I can understand in this definition, we also need some mechanism to protect the critical section of the wait() and signal() code.

But What does it mean by "we have moved busy waiting from the entry section to the critical sections of application programs"?

Why does the programmer use the semaphore under this definition need to use busy wait inside critical section of their code?

Answer (score 2):

Assume there are 10 printers and these printers are accessed using a semaphore. From the given definition of wait() and signal() the semaphore only knows the number of free printers but not the exact information on what printers are busy. So when a process acquires a semaphore it also has to obtain the specific printer it needs. This aquisition happens in the application code (which is present after the wait() function) using a mutex or some other synchronization primitives. This causes busy waiting in the application code.